# subsetting a df by group, looping through scatter plots

Tags: r, list, plot, scatter-plot, lapply

I'd like to automate generation of a few hundred scatter plots, but I'm not having much success with a compact way to handle the subsetting.  The data frame has three fields of interest:

```
site           code            value

1              x                30
1              y                14
1              z                12
2              x                35
2              y                19
```

etc,

where site= numeric, value = numeric, code = grouping variable.

There are about 400 sites and 300 codes.

What I want:

1. subset the df based on field =code
2. plot x=site vs y=value, as scatter plot
3. write each scatterplot to a separate page in a .pdf
4. automate the process

Any comments are appreciated. This approach, for example, generates the error  'subset' must evaluate to logical.  The lapply call may not work either.

```
dfarray<-list(subset(df,df[,2]))
pdf(file="test.pdf")
figures<-lapply(dfarray, function(i) {(plot(i$[,1],i$[,3]))
})
dev.off()
```

Thanks much

Incorporating d_ply worked great.  I'm happy with this result, but can anyone point out what's amiss with the label statement for the X,Y axes? (Note: this code block results in 1 pdf per subset)

```
names(df)<-tolower(names(df))
names(df)
d_ply(df,"code",function(x){
pdf(file=paste(unique(x$code),".pdf"))
plot(data=x,value~site, xlab=names(x[1]),ylab=as.name(x$code))
dev.off()
})
```

Update:  Below are two functioning versions of this code, assuming the dataframe df exists.  This one writes a scatterplot of each group to a separate .pdf:

```
names(df)<-tolower(names(df)
names(df)
d_ply(df,"code",function(x){
pdf(file=paste(unique(x$code),".pdf"))
plot(data=x, value~site, xlab=names(df[1]),ylab=unique(x$code))
dev.off()
})
```

This one writes all scatterplots, one per group, to a single .pdf:

```
names(df)<-tolower(names(df)
names(df)
pdf(file="df_all.pdf")
d_ply( df, "code", function(x) {
plot(data=x, value~site, xlab=names(df[1]), ylab=unique(x$code))
})
dev.off()
```

Comment: 1.) `paste(unique(x$code),".pdf")` results in filenames with a blank in it, i.e. `x .pdf`, `y .pdf` etc, either use `paste0` or `paste( ..., sep ="")`.
2.) `x` is a `data.frame`, so `x$code` is a vector, so probably you want to call `ylab=unique(x$code)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with `plyr::d_ply`:

```
library(plyr)
pdf(file="test.pdf")
d_ply( df.1, "code", function(x) plot( data = x, value~site, main = unique(x$code) ) )
dev.off()
```

You might want to read in general about the [split-apply-(combine) strategy](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).

Comment: The first version worked great, 1 pdf per plot.  This version generates a single .pdf-- is that right?

Comment: you are right, but this second solution matches your question: "write each scatterplot to a separate page in a .pdf"

Comment: How about adding x and y labels.  There's something amiss with my label statement, inserted into the first recasting of the code using d_ply:

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  I figured it out.  Sorry it was a trivial question.